# A-Z related to countries

Tags: knowledge, sequence, letter-sequence

**Explain this special list of -- (-) ----- and replace the question mark with the correct answer.**

```
  A (b): FRANCE
  B (d): FRANCE
  C (d): FRANCE, SWEDEN
  D:  -
  E:  -
  F (d): ENGLAND
  G (d): ENGLAND
  H (d): USA, GERMANY
  I:  - 
  J (d): ENGLAND
  K (b): IRELAND
  L:  -
  M:  -
  N (d): ENGLAND
  O (d): GERMANY
  P (d): FRANCE
  Q:  -
  R:  -
  S (d): GERMANY, SWEDEN
  T (d):  ?
  U:  -
  V (d): ITALY
  W (d): SCOTLAND, GERMANY
  X:  -
  Y:  -
  Z:  -
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The list states the

> initial letter of SI base (b) and derived (d) units. The countries are the birthplaces of the scientist.

> A (b): FRANCE - A for ampere, André-Marie Ampère
>  B (d): FRANCE - Bq for becquerel, Antoine Henri Becquerel
>  C (d): FRANCE, SWEDEN - C for coulomb, Charles-Augustin de Coulomb and °C for degree Celsius, Anders Celsius
>  F (d): ENGLAND - F for faraday, Michael Faraday
>  G (d): ENGLAND - Gy for Gray, Louis Harold Gray
>  H (d): USA, GERMANY - H for henry, Joseph Henry and Hz for hertz, Heinrich Rudolf Hertz
>  J (d): ENGLAND - J for joule, James Prescott Joule
>  K (b): IRELAND - K for kelvin, William Thomson (Lord Kelvin)
>  N (d): ENGLAND - N for newton, Isaac Newton
>  O (d): GERMANY -  Ω for ohm, Georg Simon Ohm
>  P (d): FRANCE - Pa for pascal, Blaise Pascal
>  S (d): GERMANY, SWEDEN - S for siemens Ernst Werner von Siemens and Sv for sievert, Rolf Maximilian Sievert
>  T (d):  **SERBIA - T for tesla, Nikola Tesla**
>  V (d): ITALY - V for volt,  Alessandro Volta
>  W (d): SCOTLAND, GERMANY - W for watt, James Watt and Wb for weber, Wilhelm Eduard Weber

The introduction -- (-) ----- describes

> SI Units detailed in [SI base units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SI_base_unit) and [SI derived units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SI_derived_unit)

Comment: Well done! rot13(Vg'f fcrpvny orpnhfr gurfr ner gur 19 FV havgf anzrq nsgre fpvragvfgf.)

Comment: Though rot13(Ng gur gvzr Grfyn jnf obea, ur jbhyq'ir orra va cneg bs gur Nhfgevna Rzcver, be vs lbh tb ol zbqrea zncf, uvf ovegucynpr jbhyq or va Pebngvn.  Zvabe grpuavpnyvgl.)

Comment: Even after reading the answer, I still don’t understand what the notation `-- (-) -----` is supposed to represent. Why two hyphens, then one in parentheses (presumably the b/d?), then five hyphens? What’s the meaning of the numbers two and five in particular? Especially given that the first is always **one** letter in the list, never two?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet the 2 then 5 are for [rot13](https://rot13.com/) FV Havgf and this may have a hyphen.

Comment: @Tom Ahh, of course! I saw it as representing the format of each line in the list and couldn’t make anything fit. Just me over-complicating things!

Comment: @Janus - np and I hope it's right, as now I've searched and haven't seen this written with a hyphen.